# SIGSEGV using ARCore with native android application

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, arcore

I want to use ARCore inside a native c++ android application. Therefore, I need the JNI env and context. The JNI env is provided inside the android_app struct but no context is given. I found a solution to get the android context by using the VM. But there is no valid pointer to the context.

```
JNIEnv *env = 0; // env: 0x0000007ed9bdb0c8
jobject contextObj = 0; // env: 0x0000000000000011

_pAndroidApp->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

jclass activityClass = env->FindClass("android/app/NativeActivity");  // activityClass: 0x0000000000000001

// or use: jclass activityClass = env->GetObjectClass(_pAndroidApp->activity->clazz);

jmethodID contextMethod = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "getApplicationContext", "()Landroid/content/Context;"); // contextMethod: 0x000000709660f0

contextObj = env->CallObjectMethod(_pAndroidApp->activity->clazz, contextMethod);
```

After this I want to create an ARCore session:

```
ArSession_create(_pAndroidApp->activity->env, contextObj, &ar_session_);
```

The pointer to the `contextObj` seems to be wrong. In fact, the `activityClass` seems to be wrong as well. The result creating the session is a SIGINT (signal SIGINT).

Comment: Thanks for this link. I already saw this but my problem is the obviously invalid pointer. Maybe someone else faces the same issue.

Comment: There isn't really any need for `FindClass`. You could use `env->GetObjectClass(_pAndroidApp->activity->clazz)` instead.

Comment: That's true. I have updated the question. But the problem still exists.

Comment: what is `_pAndroidApp->activity->clazz`? It should be an object instance instead of a class.

Comment: It's a reference to the NativeActivity instance created by the system.

Comment: What do you need the `Context` for exactly? To create an ARCore `Session`? Can't you just pass `_pAndroidApp->activity->clazz` instead, since a `NativeActivity` is a `Context`?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible but it didn't work for me. @see comment of the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

The java instance of the activity can be used as the context.  I created the session be calling:

```
ANativeActivity *activity = app->activity;
CHECK(ArSession_create(activity->env, activity->clazz, &ar_session_) == AR_SUCCESS);
CHECK(ar_session_);

ArConfig* ar_config = nullptr;
ArConfig_create(ar_session_, &ar_config);
CHECK(ar_config);

const ArStatus status = ArSession_checkSupported(ar_session_, ar_config);
CHECK(status == AR_SUCCESS);

CHECK(ArSession_configure(ar_session_, ar_config) == AR_SUCCESS);

ArConfig_destroy(ar_config);

ArFrame_create(ar_session_, &ar_frame_);
CHECK(ar_frame_);
```

Remember that the session creation can cause some Java exceptions for things like the phone is unsupported, or the companion app is not installed.  This will result in the the return code from ArSession_create() not being AR_SUCCESS, but something like AR_UNAVAILABLE_ARCORE_NOT_INSTALLED.  In that case, asserting is probably not the best thing to do, but rather show a message to the user.

Comment: The pointer to app->activity->clazz is 0x0000000000001f1a. Is this correct? Because if I do it your way I get an SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x2)).

Comment: clazz is a not a pointer, but a JVM object, so the low value does not surprise me.  I'll try to post a full example which help track down your issue.

Comment: That would be nice. Thank you!

Comment: I found a solution by creating a new environment for the current thread and defining the context of the application as a global reference. Now it seems to work.